# Why does Get Latest Version (Recursive) on a solution in Visual Studio 2019 (v16.6.5) download the entire branch?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfvc, solution-explorer

I am working in a development branch of our Main code branch, and in there I develop within a solution that contains a few of the projects available.
Now, I was doing a 'Get Latest Version (Recursive)' by right-clicking the solution at the top of the Solution Explorer, expecting Visual Studio to download the latest versions of the projects in the solution. What happened was that the entire branch started to download. Now that's an operation that takes about 30 minutes, and that's not how I want to spend my C:\ drive.
How can this happen?
Did I do something wrong? Are there "hidden" context menu items that I accidentally may have clicked?
Are there bugs in the 'Get Latest' procedure in VS2019?

Comment: It's going off of your workspace mapping. If you have a workspace mapped that includes an entire branch and tell it to get the root of the branch, it's going to get everything in the workspace.

Comment: Hi @Mats lsaksson. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could alleviate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I map the whole branch to the WorkSpace, I could reproduce the similar situation. The `Get Latest Version (Recursive)` will get all files in the branch.

To get files in a specific project， you could create a new Workspace in `Source Control Explorer` pointing to a separate folder, then switchover to this new workspace and do `Get Specific Version` here.

[image]

In this case, the option will only download the files in the target folder to the local.

Here is a doc about how to [Create and work with workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

As other people said here, you have to play with workspace mapping to correctly download just the folders you need to preserve disk space.

A way to to this is to use *Cloaked* status for a mapping:
[image]

*Cloaked* means it is not mapped that means that folder will not be download to disk locally in the workspace.
So an option might be to set as *Active* the parent folder of your repository than *Cloaked* all the subfolders/children folder you won't to be downloaded.